# Mongodb, how to multiple request to aliment 1 object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i'm creating a forum, and i want to get the number of message in one topic,

so in my method GetListTopic i get the list of topic, and after i want to know how many message there is in one topic so i request the table forum_message for every topic in my list=>

```js
db.Forum_Topic.count({}, function (err, topicount) { //nombre de topic 

        db.Forum_Topic.find().skip(skipNumber).limit(nombreDeTopicParPage).sort({ dateLastMessage: -1 }, function (err, dbres) { 

           
            //dbres = liste de topic 
            for (var i in dbres)
            {
                db.Forum_Message.count({ idTopic: new mongojs.ObjectID(dbres[i]._id) }, function (err, Messagecount) {
               
                  dbres[i].TotalMessage =   Messagecount;
                  
                   
                });
                
            }
            res.send([dbres, topicount]);
            

        });

    });
```

my need is to add in every object of my list the total message =>  dbres[i].TotalMessage =   Messagecount; 
but that don't work dbres[i].TotalMessage is set correctly  in the function callback but when i send object TotalMessage doesn't exist ....

someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `for` loop within an async function. And that `res.send()` statement does not wait for the loop to complete. It executes before.

There is a solution by using this [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library. There are also many options in this library, however, I think the [async.each()](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) is the one you can try.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the solution to foreach update with nodejs and mongodb, 
i use async.js here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

and to delete a liste of mail

```
async.each(ListeIdMailToDelete, function (mailID, callback) {
            db.userMessageMail.find({ _id: db.ObjectId(mailID) }, function (err, dbres) {
             if (dbres.length > 0)
              {
                  if (dbres[0].expediteur == newplayer.pseudo || dbres[0].destinataire == newplayer.pseudo) {

                                db.userMessageMail.remove({ _id: dbres[0]._id }, function () {
                                    callback(err);
                                })

                            }
                        }



                    });

                }, function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
```